Debug Linux kernel on aws environment
I use VMWare Fusion on Mac to debug linux kernels, I usually start two x86 linux vm and use the first to debug the second one, e.g https://xakcop.com/post/vmw-kernel-debugging/
Since the new M3 Mac no longer supports running x86 machines, I'm wondering if it's possible to do this on AWS? Does anyone know?
